# Extensions of an infinite product of copies of Z by Z

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, gr.group-theory, homological-algebra

The question is simple:

*Let $P$ be an infinite direct product of copies of $\mathbb Z$. Do there exist any nontrivial extensions
$$0 \to \mathbb Z \to E \to P \to 0$$
in the category of commutative groups?*

In other words, I am asking whether the group $\mathrm{Ext}^1(P,\mathbb Z)$ is trivial. The problem here is of course that the group $P$ is not a free group.

Already a funny thing happens with $\mathrm{Hom}(P,\mathbb Z)$. For any finite or infinite index set $I$, the canonical evaluation map
$$\bigoplus_{i\in I}\mathbb Z \to \mathrm{Hom}\Big(\mathrm{Hom}\Big(\bigoplus_{i\in I}\mathbb Z,\:\mathbb Z \Big),\:\mathbb Z \Big) \cong \mathrm{Hom}\Big(\prod_{i\in I}\mathbb Z,\:\mathbb Z \Big)$$
is an isomorphism! That is a nontrivial statement (due to??), whose proof is not a formality at all. Replacing $\mathbb Z$ by, say, $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$, the corresponding statement is wrong for infinite $I$.

Comment: The statement is due to Ernst Specker ("Additive Gruppen von Folgen ganzer Zahlen", Port. Math. 9, 1950).

Comment: The asserted canonical isomorphism works only if there are no measurable cardinals $\leq |I|$.  In this generality, it's due to Los (in TeX that should be {\L}o\'{s}, but I have no idea how to produce that here).  Specker did the case of countable $I$.

Comment: I think John Irwin and I once computed `$\text{Ext}^1(P,{\mathbb Z})$ and found that it's very large.  I'll look for my notes on this when I get home tonight.  Meanwhile, have you looked in Fuchs's book "Infinite Abelian Groups"?  The answer might be there.

Comment: If P is the countable direct product of $\mathbb{Z}$ and S the countable direct sum, then P/S looks like (countable product) Ext($\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$,$\mathbb{Z}$) x (uncountable sum) $\mathbb{Q}$.  So Ext(P,Z) = Ext(X,Z) x (uncountable product) $\mathbb{R}$ where  X = (countable product) (product over primes p) $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Comment: @Andreas: A simple way is to cut & paste from Wikipedia: "Łoś". :-)

Comment: Although this is an old question, I thought it would be useful to give the explicit reference in Fuchs' book, since I came across it just now. The answer is stated in exercise 2 on page 180 (at the end of chapter 13) in volume 2 of Fuchs' "Infinite Abelian Groups": Ext(P,Z) is a direct product of continuum many copies of Q/Z. In particular, its cardinality is $2^c$ where $c$ is the cardinality of the continuum.

Comment: Moreover, this answer can be simplified: Ext(P,Z) is the direct product of continuum many copies of Q/Z, so in particular it is a divisible group and so may be decomposed via the structure theory of divisible groups: it is a direct sum of $2^c$ copies of Q and $2^c$ copies of Q/Z. This is in fact how the answer is stated in [Nunke, "Slender groups", Bull. AMS, 1961].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a complete answer; I think it is more or less what Steve wrote in his comment, except I don't understand the appearance of $\mathbb{R}$ there. If $I$ is the infinite index set, let $L=\mathbb{Z}^{(I)}\subset P$ be the obvious free submodule. Then $\mathrm{Ext}^1(P,\mathbb{Z})=\mathrm{Ext}^1(P/L,\mathbb{Z})$.

EDIT: the last formula is wrong, see Martin's and Steve's comments below.

Now $P/L$ has a big divisible subgroup $D$, whose inverse image in $P$ consists of maps $I\to\mathbb{Z}$ converging to zero in $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$ (the profinite completion of $\mathbb{Z}$). (For instance, if $I=\mathbb{N}$ take the sequence $n\mapsto n!$). Since $P/L$ is torsion-free (imediate), $D$ is a nonzero $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space. Since $D$ is divisible it is a direct summand of $P/L$; hence, $P/L$ admits $\mathbb{Q}$ as a direct summand. But it is well known (and easy to see) that $\mathrm{Ext}^1(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z})\cong\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$, hence $\mathrm{Ext}^1(\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{Z})=\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}/{\mathbb{Z}}\neq0$.

Comment: The long exact sequence together with the result of Specker shows that $Ext^1(P/L,Z) \to Ext^1(P,L)$ is surjective with kernel isomorphic to $P/L$. Thus I don't understand $Ext^1(P,Z) = Ext^1(P/l,Z)$.

Comment: Oops, I'm afraid you're right. So it remains to look at the image of $P$ into $\mathrm{Ext}^1(P,\mathbb{Z})$ (easy, I think) and then see if we can exhibit something else (not so easy?).

Comment: $\mathbb{R}$ is Ext($\mathbb{Q}$,$\mathbb{Z}$).

Comment: If we're just showing Ext(P,$\mathbb{Z}$) is non-zero, we're done, since Ext(P/S, $\mathbb{Z}$) is strictly bigger than $|\mathbb{R}|$, while |P/S| = $|\mathbb{R}|$.

Comment: @Steve: Thanks, I hadn't realized that $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}/\mathbb{Z}\cong\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is given in Theorem 5 of [[Nunke, "Slender groups", Bull. AMS, 1961]](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9904-1961-10582-X): $\mathrm{Ext}^1(P,\mathbb{Z})$ is isomorphic to the direct sum of $2^{\mathfrak{c}}$ copies of $\mathbb{Q}$ and $2^{\mathfrak{c}}$ copies of $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$, where $\mathfrak{c}$ is the cardinality of the continuum. (In particular, it is very far from being trivial!) It is also stated as Exercise 2 of section 99 of [Fuchs, "Infinite Abelian Groups, Vol. II", 1973], which says that $\mathrm{Ext}^1(P,\mathbb{Z})$ is isomorphic to the direct product of $\mathfrak{c}$ copies of $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$, which one can see by the structure theory of divisible abelian groups is the same as the answer given by Nunke.