# Computation of Ext(Z^N,Z)

Tags: homological-algebra

What is $Ext_{\mathbb Z}^1 (\mathbb Z^{\mathbb N},\mathbb Z)$, where $\mathbb Z^{\mathbb N}$ stands for the infinite product $\prod_{n \in \mathbb N} \mathbb Z$?

Comment: This should answer your question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/40499/extensions-of-an-infinite-product-of-copies-of-z-by-z